# CABAC encoding - decimal to binary

Tags: encoding, floating-point, binary

On this website http://www.bilsen.com/aic/cabac.shtml there is a nice example showing how arithmetic coding works. One thing that bugs me is how this:

0.647705

got converted to this:

0.101001011101?

Clearly it's not a "typical" decimal to binary number conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0.647705 • 2 = 1 + 0.295410.
0.295410 • 2 = 0 + 0.590820.
0.590820 • 2 = 1 + 0.181640.
0.181640 • 2 = 0 + 0.363280.
0.363280 • 2 = 0 + 0.726560.
0.726560 • 2 = 1 + 0.453120.
0.453120 • 2 = 0 + 0.906240.
0.906240 • 2 = 1 + 0.812480.
0.812480 • 2 = 1 + 0.624960.
0.624960 • 2 = 1 + 0.249920.
0.249920 • 2 = 0 + 0.499840.
0.499840 • 2 = 0 + 0.999680.
```

The sequence of bits produced is 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0. Then, since we are stopping on the last one, we see the remainder, .999680, is more than ½, so we round the last bit up from 0 to 1. The result is .1010010111101.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!
One more question though. How do we know when we should stop this process? How do we know the number of bits we've produced is good enough?

Comment: From [the web site you link to](http://www.bilsen.com/aic/cabac.shtml), it is not turning the decimal into binary. Rather, it is generating binary following its algorithm, and it stops when the bits are enough to encode the message—notably when the encoded value falls within the necessary range to represent the last symbol. The article has give more of a description than an algorithm; it will take work (or reading other documents) to turn it into a proper algorithm.